# JSON file not reading by Alamofire

Tags: iphone, swift

trying to build an ios app which will locate the nearest restaurant and place it on google maps. But not able to read the JSON file.

```
var coordinate = [AnyObject]()

Alamofire.request(key).responseJSON { (response) in
        let data = response.result

        if let json =  data.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{
            if let results = json["results"]
            {
                if let geometry = results["geometry"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
                {
                    if let location = geometry["location"]
                    {
                        self.coordinate = location as! [AnyObject]
                                                }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

when I put the result in the array it gets stored but above code is not working. I want to read the geometry from the JSON file. what to do
below is the JSON file format

```
{
html_attributions: [ ],
next_page_token: "CrQCIwEAAD1hVtsv2Rq1gXGAFL67ucrXNKqh-2Km4rUSgkPUYZA4apoWTxWmUgVKX9tYTyOkHRtfU6hJsu7QBq1fZNDWB-bAcryr8ADW4bBfszYCIDkg9F2JBrxn2iMFYspvx0aQSyblSD3EoYP2qmjD4itG_pCC67Eo_Pk1Xcsoxx4ZW5O9wvtrby7WNPOUGnIlSBOZ4R-5tjwkOEZCcroM3lBjF1fQbrZ7F-2_ymgf-h3C1sdW4iV4AG85rgIcWeeAW_uwamnyvChTSqSjf_q4IiqNoA9T-q4ZmZGXgkIOk2omzjqEm1Q563RRjGXSrRV8kTeF4t_S-Xeq4-05SRwe3Gx-3t9KBDXR9W9nRH8W08H08wrBYs0O239HUXLbgGLgmZr6h8n4YQbJETLCwI_QTCtOh3sSEMCf6iNSUBjd76aHUHN1b6YaFHTkB0-5Yh8szipA_BLiVYIE0ebm",
results: [
{
geometry: {
location: {
lat: 51.51021369999999,
lng: -0.1315736
},
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 51.51158128029149,
lng: -0.130123169708498
},
southwest: {
lat: 51.5088833197085,
lng: -0.132821130291502
}
}
},
icon: "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging- 
71.png",
id: "b501c78eff5bb3e4b7f67dfe97727cec52a693c5",
name: "Thistle Piccadilly Hotel",
photos: [
{
height: 337,
html_attributions: [
"<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110195987647911662808/photos">Thistle Piccadilly Hotel</a>"
],
photo_reference: "CmRaAAAA5ohge6XYb1kjWk5C_KJdzFRx3SBF9QjkZUgUQ36av_eSP-9sjkvwncvOk5gPvVeC_Tgj4lcYr0DDm-x3JxMvnLMykI7BzAJAdoYs2VKeGNPWxX0VKdH2m72PSUScH_f4EhBJqRr0iXUwsO-IQHO2TWPGGhS8mbZaVg5BaJLnGAtE6t-cyi2naA",
width: 338
}
],
place_id: "ChIJZewrLtIEdkgRtl2nZKboAgk",
plus_code: {
compound_code: "GV69+39 St. James's, London, United Kingdom",
 global_code: "9C3XGV69+39"
},
rating: 4.4,
reference: "ChIJZewrLtIEdkgRtl2nZKboAgk",
scope: "GOOGLE",
types: [
"bar",
"lodging",
"restaurant",
"point_of_interest",
"food",
"establishment"
],
vicinity: "Coventry Street, London"
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```

How to read the latitude and longitude from the above JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a JSON value in Swift 3+ is never `AnyObject`, it's `Any`

The name `results` implies and the JSON proves it – note the `[]` – that the value is an **array**, not a dictionary

```
import CoreLocation

typealias JSONDictionary = [String:Any]

var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

Alamofire.request(key).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let json = response.result.value as? JSONDictionary,
           let results = json["results"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
            for result in results {
                if let geometry = results["geometry"] as? JSONDictionary,
                   let location = geometry["location"] as? JSONDictionary {
                      coordinates.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["lat"] as! Double, longitude: location["lng"] as! Double))
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How to read separate longitude and latitude from coordinate var?

Comment: By index: `let firstCoordinate = coordinates[0]` on in a loop: `for coordinate in coordinates { .. }`

Comment: `for cor in coordinates
        {
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: cor.latitude, longitude: cor.longitude, zoom: 14)
            
            let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.myView.frame.size.width, height: self.myView.frame.size.height), camera: camera)
            let marker = GMSMarker()
            marker.position = camera.target
            marker.map = mapView
            self.myView.addSubview(mapView)
        }` trying to insert multilple marker but only one marker get added on the map

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Maps but you are creating a new map view in each iteration of the loop, most likely this is not intended

Answer (score 0):

You can use SwiftyJSON. It is easier to parse your JSON data.

```
    var coordinate = [AnyObject]()

    Alamofire.request(key).responseJSON { (response) in
        let data = response.result
        let json = try JSON(data: data)
        let results = json["results"].array
        for result in results{
            let location = result["geometry"]["location"]
            coordinates.append((location["lat"], location["lng"]))

        }
    }
```